# How to make to_string stop at the right time when processing fractional parts

Tags: c++, binary

I wrote a `to_string` function for my string library and the main part of it looks like this

```cpp
template<typename T>
inline string num_base(T num,size_t radix,const string radix_table)noexcept{
    string aret;
    do{//do while, also has a return value when num is 0
        T first_char_index{};
        if constexpr(::std::is_floating_point_v<T>)
            first_char_index= ::std::fmod(num,(T)radix);
        else
            first_char_index= num%radix;
        if constexpr(::std::is_floating_point_v<T>)
            num-=first_char_index;
        num/=(T)radix;
        aret.push_front(radix_table[(size_t)first_char_index]);
    }
    while(num);
    return aret;
}
template<typename T>
inline string num_base_mantissa(T num,size_t radix,const string radix_table)noexcept{
    string aret;
    while(num){
        num*=radix;
        T first_char_index;
        num=::std::modf(num,&first_char_index);
        aret+=radix_table[(size_t)first_char_index];
    }
    return aret;
}
```

The detailed definitions are [here](https://github.com/ELC-lang/ELC/blob/d6eb81fec3a56552c5035d1c8ce236deb48dad14/parts/header_file/files/elc/_files/string/to_string.hpp), in case anyone still doesn't understand my vague rhetoric

When I tested this function, it worked fine until it ran into `(double)1.1`:

It outputs `"1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625"`

I looked up the reason for this and it seems to be because the underlying binary representation cannot express `1.1`, so it has to be approximated instead, but my `to_string` outputs this approximation as is

I tested `std::to_string` again and it outputs `1.1` nicely instead of a long string of stuff

I'd like to know how I can modify my function to be less strict as std's version?

Comment: If you are not interested in all 53 digits of a `double` value, you will have to tell your function explicitly when it has to stop. I very much doubt that there is a general "you can stop here" method.

Comment: `std::to_string` uses the default output settings; six significant digits, no trailing zeros. You need to add that logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally from my friend's idea, I now renamed the original `to_string` to `to_string_rough` and built the `to_string` from `to_string_rough` and `from_string_get`!

Under the assumption that decimal is used (for ease of example), `to_string` will first obtain the processing result of `to_string_rough` and attempt to process the case of `list_length` consecutive zeros or `list_length` nines in the decimal part.

- When consecutive `0`s are detected, remove this straight and the part after it
- When consecutive `9`s are detected, remove as above and round up the previous digit

The result is processed by `from_string_get`, which does a **reverse** (string-to-floating-point) process and compares it to the original number; if it is full identical, `to_string` returns the simplified content; if not, `to_string` continues to process the string until string was end

For more details, see [this commit](https://github.com/ELC-lang/ELC/commit/4263cd446b785070983a439afeafc6538d9eef0f)

```
1.1
1.1(1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625)
1.12
1.12(1.12000000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875)
1.1314
1.1314(1.1313999999999999612754209010745398700237274169921875)
1.216543215432
1.216543215432(1.21654321543199994692940890672616660594940185546875)
1.3
1.3(1.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125)
```

For the tests so far, it works well

---

Update: After half a day we switched to a faster lookup method (dichotomy) to determine the appropriate value for the truncation loci, but the basic idea remained the same, still requiring a *reverse* conversion to ensure that truncation would not affect data recovery

The implementation can be seen [here](https://github.com/ELC-lang/ELC/compare/4263cd446b785070983a439afeafc6538d9eef0f...52405c3e2b9c999e21137bac48ff8ccb9d3e7dee)

```
1530.5468561213215646
1530.5468561213215(1530.54685612132152527919970452785491943359375)
1530.5468561213215
1530.5468561213215(1530.54685612132152527919970452785491943359375)
1.12135
1.12135(1.121350000000000068922645368729718029499053955078125)
1.21264
1.21264(1.212639999999999940172301648999564349651336669921875)
54320.215644444444444444444444444445
54320.21564444444(54320.215644444440840743482112884521484375)
21606.1456448565465463218976546
21606.145644856548(21606.14564485654773307032883167266845703125)
21606.145644856548
21606.145644856548(21606.14564485654773307032883167266845703125)
```

The new method is much smarter and faster

---

Another update: I've used *[epsilon](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon)* to improve the processing of `to_string_rough`, something like [this](https://github.com/ELC-lang/ELC/commit/ff526b53efd63cdbb5d688a536fedff4aa7b1e26) & [this](https://github.com/ELC-lang/ELC/commit/1c95716fe70d291ddb32bc6c8d12a4e267e4098c)

```
template<typename T>
inline string num_base_mantissa(T num,size_t radix,const string radix_table)noexcept{
    string aret;
-   while(num){
+   T      epsilon = ::std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon();
+   while(num >= epsilon){
        num*=radix;
+       epsilon*=radix;
        T first_char_index;
        num=::std::modf(num,&first_char_index);
        aret+=radix_table[(size_t)first_char_index];
    }
    return aret;
}
```

So now that `to_string_rough` is mostly as smart as `to_string` (and there still is no data loss in the conversion), there are still a few times when need to process it further

```
1.1
1.1(1.1)
1.2
1.2(1.1999999999999999)
1.4
1.4(1.3999999999999999)
1.123456789
1.123456789(1.123456789)
1.1234567891504554
1.1234567891504554(1.1234567891504554)
1.1234567891504554130543435
1.1234567891504554(1.1234567891504554)
```

---

Another update: it seems that using epsilon in `to_string_rough` causes `to_string` to fail to handle *superfine* numbers like `0.3000000000000001`, although I don't know why, I've stoped the use of epsilon.

---

Another update: I've added something called [information threshold](https://github.com/ELC-lang/ELC/commit/47d993e945620c0430ab9093cf5c64d5387de308) to prevent infinite loops caused by situations like displaying 0.25 in trinary, which I've listed here in case anyone else takes the wrong turn in future